# R: stringsAsFactors in SQL Query using ROracle package

Tags: r, roracle

I am having a hard time with changing character columns to factors direct in SQL Query. I have tried different approaches: `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`, I have tried as well changing character columns directly, but nothing was working. Does anyone have an idea how to approach this problem?

Example SQL Query:

```
sqlInput <- paste("select * from x.y where a =",paste0("'",d(),"'"), "ORDER BY Datum asc")
dbGetQuery(con$cc, sqlInput)
```

I have tried

```
dbGetQuery(con$cc, sqlInput, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

but it didn't bring any results.

I have tried as well:

```
character_vars <- lapply(data, class) == "character"
data[, character_vars] <- lapply(data[, character_vars], as.factor)
```

but neither this brought any results...

Just changing each and every character column separately gave me the solution:

```
data$a <- as.factor(as.character(data$a))
```

However in my case there are too many character columns so manual selection is not possible.

Any ideas how to change strings to factors directly in SQL part (`dbGetQuery()`)?

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious to know how your lapply piece of code does not give any good result... the code it's perfectly fine

Comment: Sorry i just have noticed that the problem is on the other side --> `DT` package of my ShinyApp. My fault..However answer if it is possible to change strings to factors in SQL part is still interesting and valuable!